# using Regular Expression in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

It's the first time trying to use Regular Expression. I am trying to match Australian Post code(i.e 4 digit) , but my noOFMatches gets no . of digits +1 (9 in this case)in it. I know it's something silly that i cannot figure out. Pls suggest. 
I feel if I pass 4 digit nos. in postcode then noOfMatches should get 1 . is that correct?

```
  NSString *postCode = @"12345676";
    NSRegularExpression *regularExpression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(|d{4})" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];

  int noOfMatches = [ regularExpression numberOfMatchesInString:field.text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0,  [postCode length])];
```

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track, although the pattern you've used isn't correct and that's why it returns 9 matches.

It's an easy fix:

```
([0-9]{4})
```

or

```
(\\d{4})
```

Should give you the correct result: **2**

Answer (score 0):

You should use a regex tester, eg http://regexpal.com/

Native iOS regex is ridiculously clumsy and lengthy. If you work with regex alot, I'd recommend using a library, such as https://github.com/bendytree/Objective-C-RegEx-Categories